# Why a thread would interrupt another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

In Java multi threaded applications, we deal with InterruptedThreadException. This Exception is thrown if another thread interrupts the current thread. Now what is the reason another thread might want to interrupt the current thread when it knows that it is going to cause an Exception?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225194/what-kind-of-behaviour-causes-an-interrupted-exception

Answer (score 4):

Many reasons. But the most popular one is to cancel some task on a thread.

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html for details.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, to notify that a `Thread` should abort. Usually, a worker thread executing some sort of batch operation is implemented in a way that it terminates itself (i.e. exit out of its `run()` method) when interrupted.

Unfortunately, a lot of programmers simply catch and swallow it which is a very very bad practice. If a `Thread` is not expecting an `InterruptedException` it should either re-throw or should restore its interrupted status if it cannot *throw* it (if restrained by an *Interface* for example) by calling

```
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Please explain the down vote.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense to me. Probably someone who got offended because he was eating all his InterruptedExceptions'.

Comment: You guys don't know Java you can eat interrupted exception any time you want I been doing it for years